# Oracle SQL query : finding the last time a data was changed

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to retrieve elapsed days since the last time the data of the specific column was changed, for example :

TABLE_X contains

```
ID   PDATE        DATA1    DATA2
A    10-Jan-2013   5       10
A     9-Jan-2013   5       10
A     8-Jan-2013   5       11
A     7-Jan-2013   5       11
A     6-Jan-2013  14       12
A     5-Jan-2013  14       12
B    10-Jan-2013   3       15
B     9-Jan-2013   3       15
B     8-Jan-2013   9       15
B     7-Jan-2013   9       15
B     6-Jan-2013  14       15
B     5-Jan-2013  14        8
```

I simplify the table for example purpose.

The result should be :

```
ID  DATA1_LASTUPDATE  DATA2_LASTUPDATE
A   4                 2
B   2                 5
```

which says, 
- data1 of A last update is 4 days ago, 
- data2 of A last update is 2 days ago, 
- data1 of B last update is 2 days ago, 
- data2 of B last update is 5 days ago.

Using query below is OK but it takes too long to complete if I apply it to the real table which have lots of records and add 2 more data columns to find their latest update days.
I use LEAD function for this purposes.
Any other alternatives to speed up the query?

```
with qdata1 as
(
    select ID, pdate from
    (
        select a.*, row_number() over (partition by ID order by pdate desc) rnum from
        (
            select a.*,
                   lead(data1,1,0) over (partition by ID order by pdate desc) - data1 as data1_diff
            from table_x a
        ) a
        where data1_diff <> 0
    )
    where rnum=1
),
qdata2 as
(
    select ID, pdate from
    (
        select a.*, row_number() over (partition by ID order by pdate desc) rnum from
        (
            select a.*,
                   lead(data2,1,0) over (partition by ID order by pdate desc) - data2 as data2_diff
            from table_x a
        ) a
        where data2_diff <> 0
    )
    where rnum=1
)
select a.ID,
       trunc(sysdate) - b.pdate data1_lastupdate,
       trunc(sysdate) - c.pdate data2_lastupdate,
from table_master a, qdata1 b, qdata2 c
where a.ID=b.ID(+) and a.ID=b.ID(+)
  and a.ID=c.ID(+) and a.ID=c.ID(+)
```

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can avoid the multiple hits on the table and the joins by doing both lag (or lead) calculations together:

```
with t as (
  select id, pdate, data1, data2,
    lag(data1) over (partition by id order by pdate) as lag_data1,
    lag(data2) over (partition by id order by pdate) as lag_data2
  from table_x
),
u as (
  select t.*,
    case when lag_data1 is null or lag_data1 != data1 then pdate end as pdate1,
    case when lag_data2 is null or lag_data2 != data2 then pdate end as pdate2
  from t
),
v as (
  select u.*,
    rank() over (partition by id order by pdate1 desc nulls last) as rn1,
    rank() over (partition by id order by pdate2 desc nulls last) as rn2
  from u
)
select v.id,
  max(trunc(sysdate) - (case when rn1 = 1 then pdate1 end))
    as data1_last_update,
  max(trunc(sysdate) - (case when rn2 = 1 then pdate2 end))
    as data2_last_update
from v
group by v.id
order by v.id;
```

I'm *assuming* that you meant your data to be for `Jun-2014`, not `Jan-2013`; and that you're comparing the most recent change dates with the current date. With the data adjusted to use `10-Jun-2014` etc., this gives:

```
ID DATA1_LAST_UPDATE DATA2_LAST_UPDATE
-- ----------------- -----------------
A                  4                 2 
B                  2                 5
```

The first CTE (`t`) gets the actual table data and adds two extra columns, one for each of the data columns, using lag (whic his the the same as lead ordered by descending dates).

The second CTE (`u`) adds two date columns that are only set when the data columns are changed (or when they are first set, just in case they have never changed). So if a row has `data1` the same as the previous row, its `pdate1` will be blank. You could combine the first two by repeating the lag calculation but I've left it split out to make it a bit clearer.

The third CTE (`v`) assigns a ranking to those `pdate` columns such that the most recent is ranked first.

And the final query works out the difference from the current date to the highest-ranked (i.e. most recent) change for each of the data columns.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ec3c8/1), including all the CTEs run individually so you can see what they are doing.

Comment: I have tried your suggested query and yes it is faster. Thanks. My query took 1 minutes and 8 to 30 seconds (I dont know what caused this fluctuation) and your query took 56 seconds. Fyi the real TABLE_X data is a UNION of 2 tables with all total records is about 6 millions records. The number of unique ID is 6 thousands items and the ID that meets the criteria of the filter is about 1,250 records (I add the filter query inside the sub query).

Comment: I add additional filter and now it took 22 seconds while my previous query took 35 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Your query wasn't returning the right results for me, maybe I missed something, but I got the correct results also with the below query (you can check this [SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/2ee1e/29)):

```
with ranked as (
                  select ID, 
                         data1,
                         data2,   
                         rank() over(partition by id order by pdate desc) r 
                  from table_x
               )
select id,
       sum(DATA1_LASTUPDATE) DATA1_LASTUPDATE,
       sum(DATA2_LASTUPDATE) DATA2_LASTUPDATE
from (
     -- here I get when data1 was updated
         select id, 
                count(1) DATA1_LASTUPDATE,
                0 DATA2_LASTUPDATE
           from ranked
     start with r = 1
    CONNECT BY (PRIOR data1 = data1)
           and PRIOR r = r - 1
      group by id
    union 
  -- here I get when data2 was updated
        select id, 
               0 DATA1_LASTUPDATE,
               count(1) DATA0_LASTUPDATE  
           from ranked
     start with r = 1
    CONNECT BY (PRIOR data2 = data2)
           and PRIOR r = r - 1
      group by id
)  
group by id
```

Comment: I forgot to tell that in my query I use SYSDATE for latest date, but for the data sample I should edit my query using 10-Jan-2013 as latest date not sysdate. I have tried you suggested query but it took lot longer than mine.